# Where is my error in this query?, I think it's correct but, it marks an error

Tags: mysql

Well, I'm doing this Select where I search into a database for an information.
I'm programming in java, and my query in M is this:

```
SELECT * FROM detalle_reserva WHERE fechaInicio='2015-08-13' AND id_mesa=4 AND periodo='comida'
```

and it works on sqlyog, but at the moment when I put it into the program I get this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'periodo='Comida'' at line 1

I have a function that recieves 3 variables which are: fechaInicio,idMesa and periodo. This is the line where I put it:

```
 this.sqlConsulta = "select * from detalle_reserva where fechaInicio="+"'"+fechaIni+"'"+"and id_mesa="+idMesa+"and periodo="+"'"+periodo+"'";
```

Can anybody tell me where am I wrong?

This is the entire function:

```
public ResultSet verificar(String fechaIni,int idMesa, String periodo){
    conectar();
    registro=null;
    try{
        this.sqlConsulta = "select * from detalle_reserva where fechaInicio="+"'"+fechaIni+"'"+"and id_mesa="+idMesa+"and periodo="+"'"+periodo+"'";
        PreparedStatement sentencia = conexion.prepareStatement(sqlConsulta);

      // sentencia.setString(1, periodo);
        registro = sentencia.executeQuery();
         }   catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error al consultar: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return registro;
}
```

Comment: Don't use prepared statements that way (you are defeating the whole purpose) use the '?' please holders and bind parameters. Your string concatanation is probably introducing errors.

Comment: I used first the ? on every field on the where condition is, but it was the same, and then I tried this way, and I didn't change it, as you can see there is a comment inside the function where I was seding the variables to the syntax, there is one, because I deleted the other 2 but, and i was trying with the one i had the problem

Comment: Is the query that you manually typed into the console the exact same as what your code executes? You will be able to see what query is being executed if you look at the mysql server log

Comment: The problem here would be obvious if you'd generate that query in a string and examine what's in the string before sending it to the server... however, you are using prepared statements incorrectly.  If you used it correctly -- with `?` placeholders and no string concatenation,  you would not have made this simple mistake.  There are at least 2 syntax errors in the string you are generating. The errors appear to be near `+"and` vs `+" and`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you by chance forget to copy  the semicolon or purposely don't have one? Sometimes you can omit the semicolon; however, If the system gets confused, it matters.

```
SELECT * FROM detalle_reserva WHERE fechaInicio='2015-08-13' AND id_mesa=4 AND periodo='comida';
```

Comment: I did it on purpose, I have no problem executing the query on sqlyog, the problem is at the moment i try to do the select in the program.
The query runs with or without the semicolon in sqlyog